# EG(function_table) Structre's content

Tags: php, c

I took a look at the source code of PHP in order to learn a bit.

I came across `/PHP_5_2/Zend/zend_builtin_functions.c` and saw over there
the next line:

```
 retval = (zend_hash_find(EG(function_table), lcname, Z_STRLEN_PP(function_name)+1, (void **)&func) == SUCCESS);
```

I'm interested in the next part of this line:

```
zend_hash_find(EG(function_table), lcname,
```

I don't know `C` that well but I can guess that `zend_has_find` is looking for a value which its key is `lcname` in the `EG(function_table)`.
I know that this `EG(function_table)` exists in both the compiler and executor globals. Iterating through this hashtable gives you every callable function.

I can't edit my server's php source code , is there a way (or a wiki) of that `EG(function_table)` structre?

To be more specific , Is there a way to see the information about the functions it contains?

Thanks.